# Incremental data load using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to implement incremental data import using pandas.

I have two dataframes: df_old (original data, loaded before) and df_new (new data, to be merged with df_old).

data in df_old/df_new are unique on multiple columns 
(for simplicity, lets say just 2: key1 and key2). other columns are data to be merged and lets say, they are only 2 of them too: val1 and val2.

beside these, there is one more column to be taken care of: change_id - it increases for each new entry overwriting the old one

the logic of import is pretty straightforward:

1. if there is new key pair in df_new, it should be added (with corresponding val1/val2 values) to df_old
2. if there is a key pair in df_new which exists in df_old, then:

   2a) if corresponding values in df_old and df_new are same, the old ones should be kept

   2b) if corresponding values in df_old and df_new are different, the values in df_new should replace the old ones in df_old
3. there's no need to care about dala deletion (if some data in df_old exist, which are not present in df_new)

so far, I came up with 2 different solutions:

```
>>> df_old = pd.DataFrame([['A1','B2',1,2,1],['A1','A2',1,3,1],['B1','A2',1,3,1],['B1','B2',1,4,1],], columns=['key1','key2','val1','val2','change_id'])
>>> df_old.set_index(['key1','key2'], inplace=True)
>>> df_old

           val1  val2  change_id
key1 key2                       
A1   B2       1     2          1
     A2       1     3          1
B1   A2       1     3          1
     B2       1     4          1

>>> df_new = pd.DataFrame([['A1','B2',2,1,2],['A1','A2',1,3,2],['C1','B2',2,1,2]], columns=['key1','key2','val1','val2','change_id'])
>>> df_new.set_index(['key1','key2'], inplace=True)
>>> df_new

           val1  val2  change_id
key1 key2                       
A1   B2       2     1          2
     A2       1     3          2
C1   B2       2     1          2
```

solution 1

```
# this solution groups concatenated old data with new ones, group them by keys and for each group evaluates if new data are different
def merge_new(x):    
    if x.shape[0] == 1:
        return x.iloc[0]
    else: 
        if x.iloc[0].loc[['val1','val2']].equals(x.iloc[1].loc[['val1','val2']]):
            return x.iloc[0]
        else:
            return x.iloc[1]

def solution1(df_old, df_new):
    merged = pd.concat([df_old, df_new]) 
    return merged.groupby(level=['key1','key2']).apply(merge_new).reset_index()
```

solution 2

```
# this solution uses pd.merge to merge data + additional logic to compare merged rows and select new data
>>> def solution2(df_old, df_new):
>>>    merged = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', suffixes=('_old','_new'), indicator='ind')
>>>    merged['isold'] = (merged.loc[merged['ind'] == 'both',['val1_old','val2_old']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-4]) == merged.loc[merged['ind'] == 'both',['val1_new','val2_new']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-4])).all(axis=1)
>>>    merged.loc[merged['ind'] == 'right_only','isold'] = False    
>>>    merged['isold'] = merged['isold'].fillna(True)
>>>    return pd.concat([merged[merged['isold'] == True][['val1_old','val2_old','change_id_old']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-4]), merged[merged['isold'] == False][['val1_new','val2_new','change_id_new']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-4])])

>>> solution1(df_old, df_new)

  key1 key2  val1  val2  change_id
0   A1   A2     1     3          1
1   A1   B2     2     1          2
2   B1   A2     1     3          1
3   B1   B2     1     4          1
4   C1   B2     2     1          2


>>> solution2(df_old, df_new)

           val1  val2  change_id
key1 key2                       
A1   A2     1.0   3.0        1.0
B1   A2     1.0   3.0        1.0
     B2     1.0   4.0        1.0
A1   B2     2.0   1.0        2.0
C1   B2     2.0   1.0        2.0
```

Both of the work, however, I am still quite dissapointed with the performance on huge dataframes.
the question is: is there some better way to do this? any hint for decent speed improvement will be more than welcome...

```
>>> %timeit solution1(df_old, df_new)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop

>>> %timeit solution2(df_old, df_new)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is there any library for this? I feel this is a very common thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do this that's pretty fast:

```
merged = pd.concat([df_old.reset_index(), df_new.reset_index()])
merged = merged.drop_duplicates(["key1", "key2", "val1", "val2"]).drop_duplicates(["key1", "key2"], keep="last")
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop

#   key1 key2  val1  val2  change_id
# 1   A1   A2     1     3          1
# 2   B1   A2     1     3          1
# 3   B1   B2     1     4          1
# 0   A1   B2     2     1          2
# 2   C1   B2     2     1          2
```

The rationale here is to concatenate all rows and simply call `drop_duplicates` twice, rather than relying on join logic to get the rows you want. The first call to `drop_duplicates` drops rows originating in `df_new` that match on both the key & value columns since the default behavior of this method is to keep the first of the duplicate rows (in this case the row from `df_old`). The second call drops duplicates that match on the key columns, but specifies that the `last` row for each set of duplicates should be kept.

This approach assumes that the rows are sorted on `change_id`; this is a safe assumption given the order in which the example DataFrames are concatenated. If this is a faulty assumption with your real data, however, simply call `.sort_values('change_id')` on `merged` before dropping the duplicates.